# $P,Q$ are positive definite diagonal matrices. $A,B$ are matrices, then $\lVert PA - QB \rVert_2 \leq \max(\rho(P),\rho(Q)) \lVert A - B \rVert_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

$P,Q$ are positive definite diagonal $n \times n$ matrices with $\rho(P),\rho(Q) < 1$. $A,B$ are $n \times m$ matrices. Prove that

$\lVert PA - QB \rVert_2 \leq \max(\rho(P),\rho(Q)) \lVert A - B \rVert_2$

where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ is the 2-norm and $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius.

I am not sure if this result is even true - but it would great to get a pointer toward either a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true in general. Try $n = 2$, $A = B = I$, $Q = I$, $P = \pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$. Then $PA - QB$ is nonzero, but $A - B$ is zero.

In fact, even for $n = 1$ it seems to be false, for if $a = b = 1$, $p = 2$ and $q = 1$, your formula says that
$$
|2-1| < \max(1, 2) |1 - 1|.
$$

Comment: ahh, thank you!

Comment: I should add an extra condition then, that the eigenvlaues of $P,Q$ lie in $(0,1)$

Comment: Pick $a = b = 1, p = 0.5, q = 0.6$ and you've still got a counterexample for $n = 1$. I think you should really consider why you believe that this might be true, and  keep in mind the case $A = B$ as you examine your reasons. that's always going to make the right-hand side be zero, and it's really tough to prove inequalities with zeroes on the right.

Comment: actually - even with this extra condition - I think the statement is still false.

Comment: ahh you got there before me, thanks again

Comment: as you suggest, I will consider this more carefully.